# Listener lsnrctl start TNS-00515: Connect failed because target host or object does not exist 64-bit Windows Error: 1004: Unknown error

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, listener

I cannot get my listener to start, I have spent hours searching forums and couldn't find any solution.
My goal is to start APEX, but first I have to get listener up&running, when I try, I'm getting:

C:\Users\matulewi>lsnrctl start

LSNRCTL for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on 28-GRU-2015 15:20:45

Copyright (c) 1991, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Starting tnslsnr: please wait...

TNSLSNR for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
System parameter file is C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\network\admin\listener.ora
Log messages written to C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\diag\tnslsnr\MATULEWI1\listener\alert\log.xml
Listening on: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(PIPENAME=\.\pipe\EXTPROC1ipc)))
Error listening on: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=MATULEWI1.emea.xxxxx.net)(PORT=1521))) 
TNS-12545: Connect failed because target host or object does not exist
TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
  TNS-00515: Connect failed because target host or object does not exist
   64-bit Windows Error: 1004: Unknown error

My tnsnames.ora:

XE =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = MATULEWI1.emea.xxxxx.net)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
    )
  )

EXTPROC_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = PLSExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )

ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = CLRExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )

listener.ora:

SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = PLSExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
    )
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
    )
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = MATULEWI1.emea.xxxxx.net)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )

DEFAULT_SERVICE_LISTENER = (XE)

Could somebody please help out?

k.

Comment: Can you resolve the address `MATULEWI1.emea.xxxxx.net` from the Windows command line (nslookup, or ping it)? Does the IP address it resolves to correspond to an interface on your PC? Is there a firewall blocking port 1521? It may be worth considering if you actually need the listener to be on the public IP; if user access will be via Apex may e you want it on localhost anyway.

Answer (score 8):

I got this error because I renamed my computer.

Fixed it when I corrected the listener.ora file.

```
(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = YourComputerName)(PORT = 1521))
```

Comment: Perfect. You saved one's day!